# Opencart - изменение регистрации пользователя

Tags: opencart

Доброго времени суток. Нужно в Opencar изменить стандартную регистрацию пользователя. Задача заключается в том чтоб убрать поля с вводом пароля и его подтверждением, а вместо этого пароль должен случайным образом генерироваться и  приходить на почту клиенту. Сами поля то я убрал, но куда копать дальше понятия не имею(новичок)... Подскажите правильный путь решение этой задачи, спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

При отправки данных на сервер можно сделать генерацию паролей

```
<?php 
$chars="qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp1234567890QAZXSWEDCVFRTGBNHYUJMKIOLP"; 
$max=10; 
$size=StrLen($chars)-1; 
$password=null; 
while($max--) 
$password.=$chars[rand(0,$size)]; 
echo $password;
```

`$password` - здесь ваш пароль запишите его в базу, а в письмо добавить пароль который получился.